# How to continue to getting data even the previous ID is returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```
public bool GetStudentResult()
{

       List<L0Student> studentList = _StudentIdRepository.GetAll();
       foreach (var item in studentList )
       {
              this.GetStudentExamResult(item.StudentID);
              this.GetStudentPreviousYearRseult(item.StudentID);
       }
       return true;
}
```

```
public bool GetStudentPreviousYearRseult(int StudentID)
{
       List<ExamResultPast> examresultPast = _ExamResultPastRepo.FindByStudentId(StudentID); //Student A will return null since there is not past year result
       foreach (var item in examresultPast)
       {
              //Data.....
              _ExamResultPastRepo.Update(Data);
       }
       return true;
}
```

In a scenario where Student A is a transfer student that doesn't have any record of Previous Year Result in School A. While Student B had both the exam result.
When the system is finding Student past exam result it can't find it, so the system will return null. Will the bool been terminate the Student A past exam result can't be found. If the system is been terminated. How can I proceed to Student B so that It can continue getting the result.

Comment: remove the  `return true` from method`GetStudentPreviousYearRseult` and declare it as `void` in place of `bool`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the method `GetStudentPreviousYearRseult`  returning as `void` not `bool`. because you don't need its return value as per your requirement. and also you can add a `null` check for `examresultPast`  before the `foreach` loop.

```
public void GetStudentPreviousYearRseult(int StudentID)
{
       List<ExamResultPast> examresultPast = _ExamResultPastRepo.FindByStudentId(StudentID); //Student A will return null since there is not past year result
       if(examresultPast != null)
       {
           foreach (var item in examresultPast)
           {
              //Data.....
              _ExamResultPastRepo.Update(Data);
           }
       }
}
```